# WINAPI Window, not being created

Tags: c++, winapi, winmain

I have been trying very hard to get my window to work. I am looking at the MSDN Page on how to make a window and i can't see the difference. When i run my program, it comes up with the message box saying NO WINDOW.

Code:

```
#include <windows.h>

static const LPSTR CLASSNAME = "Win32Window";

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND window, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        DefWindowProc(window, msg, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR cmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ARROW));
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.lpszClassName = CLASSNAME;
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to register window class", "ERROR", MB_ICONERROR);
        return 1;
    }

    HWND window = CreateWindow(CLASSNAME, "title", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!window)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "NO WINDOW", "ERROR", MB_ICONERROR); // THIS IS BEING CALLED!!!! WHY??
        return 1;
    }

    ShowWindow(window, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(window);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.lParam;
}
```

If someone can tell me what is wrong here that would be great.

Comment: Try to examine what the error was using `GetLastError`.  Most likely there's a problem with some of the arguments in `wcex` or `CreateWindow`.

Comment: I am very new to C++ and i don't really know how to do this.

Comment: OK I managed to do it but it just returned 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your window procedure (`WndProc`) needs to return the value returned by `DefWindowProc`. At the moment you're just returning 0 for all unhandled messages, which has side effects like (in response to `WM_NCCREATE`) causing your window creation to fail.